# Simple C++ while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm having trouble solving this problem from my c++ book, and there isn't a good example.

> Write a code that lets users enter a number. The number should be multiplied by 2 and printed until the number exceeds 50. Use a while loop.

I suppose I should post my attempt, though I know it's nowhere near ready:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";

    multiply = number * 2;

    while (number <= 50)
    {

        cin >> number;
        cout << multiply;
    }
}
```

What needs to be added or deleted? Maybe someone has a link to a similar source code?

Feel free to change variable names or anything. Please ask for changes or more information before down-voting. thank you.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Arguably, the code as is does meet the requirement . . .

Comment: You're multiplying number by 2 ... but seemingly never utilising the result (stored in the "multiply" variable).
Is this expected?

Comment: well I'm very lost. What needs to be added or deleted? Maybe someone has a link to a similar source code?

Comment: no I complied it it's not doing what the problem asks for

Comment: What do you currently think `multiply = number * 2;` does?

Comment: multiply "number" by 2. ah I meant to output that. I'll tweak my code a little

Comment: @Zack A program is executed top-down.  Read your `main` function and follow what it does, starting from the top.  You declare a variable called `number` and it was never given a value.  After that you display a prompt.  Next line you multiply `number` by 2.  So where was `number` ever inputted by the user in those steps?  Doesn't it sound like you forgot something?

Comment: multiply is not declared , put the *2 inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. As per your question, the number needs to be doubled when entered, so you just need to move your multiplication within the loop, so that there a number to x2. Otherwise, there is no value for 'number' till that point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number, multiply=1;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    multiply = number * 2;

    while (multiply<= 50)
    {

        cout << multiply;
        multiply*=2;
    }

return;
}
```

Comment: hmm it seems to just print one number for me

Comment: It'll keep printing as you enter numbers. That's what the question's asking for yeah? If not, I've edited it. See if this works.

Comment: I think it's suppose to just keep doubling the number until it hits 50. like you put in 4 and a line of code will come out "8 16 32" but not 64

Comment: I've made the changes :)

Comment: If you don't mind, please mark the question as answered with whichever answer you feel does it. Some of us are trying to get enough rep points to ask questions of our own with screenshots (requires 150rep lol)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";

   cin >> number;

    while (number <= 50)
    {
        cout << number
         number *= 2;
    }
}
```